# Getting data of a box plot - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have to plot a boxplot of some data, which I could easily do with **Matplotlib**. However, I was requested to provide a table with the data presented there, like the whiskers, the medians, standard deviation, and so on.

I know that I could calculate these "by hand", but I also know, from the reference, that the `boxplot` method:

```
Returns a dictionary mapping each component of the boxplot to a list of the matplotlib.lines.Line2D instances created. That dictionary has the following keys (assuming vertical boxplots):

boxes: the main body of the boxplot showing the quartiles and the median’s confidence intervals if enabled.
medians: horizonal lines at the median of each box.
whiskers: the vertical lines extending to the most extreme, n-outlier data points.
caps: the horizontal lines at the ends of the whiskers.
fliers: points representing data that extend beyone the whiskers (outliers).
```

So I'm wondering how could I get these values, since they are **matplotlib.lines.Line2D**.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with calculating these "by hand"? Most of this information is easily available with `numpy`, e.g. with `np.median`, or `np.min` and `np.max`.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: Particularly for large datasets this is duplication of effort as more costly functions, such as `median` have already been called when creating the boxplot.

Comment: Exactly, @jmetz! Cause of these I wondering how to get these values from the already calculated box plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've figured out, you need to access the members of the return value of boxplot.

Namely, e.g. if your return value is stored in `bp`

```
bp['medians'][0].get_ydata()

>> array([ 2.5,  2.5])
```

As the boxplot is vertical, and the *median line is therefore a horizontal line*, you only need to focus on one of the y-values; i.e. the median is 2.5 for my sample data.

For each "key" in the dictionary, the value will be a list to handle for multiple boxes. If you have just one boxplot, the list will only have one element, hence my use of `bp['medians']`**[0]** above. 
If you have multiple boxes in your boxplot, you will need to iterate over them using e.g.

```
for medline in bp['medians']:
    linedata = medline.get_ydata()
    median = linedata[0]
```

CT Zhu's answer doesn't work unfortunately, as the different elements behave differently. Also e.g. there's only one median, but two whiskers...therefore it's safest to manually treat each quantity as outlined above.

NB the closest you can come is the following;

```
res  = {}
for key, value in bp.items():
    res[key] = [v.get_data() for v in value]
```

or equivalently

```
res = {key : [v.get_data() for v in value] for key, value in bp.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you! In `bp['medians'][0]`, why the [0]?  This isn't the same as `bp['medians']` if I just had one box plot? And why this return an array of two values? I'm asking this 'cause I'm wondering if I have to look to the first or to the second one, or if they you be the same, which doesn't seems to make sense.

Comment: Even if you have just one box plot the return is a one-element list. The y-data has two values because it's a line with a start point and an end point (with the same y-value as it's horizontal)

Comment: Understood. (: For `for key, value in bp:` I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Comment: @pceccon: opps yeah forgot .items() after bp. Updated answer

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But this gives another error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_ydata'`. Trying to figure out how to access this content.

Comment: Ah right, then I forgot the iteration over the list items

Comment: And I tried this too, which gives the error `IndexError: index out of bounds`. :S

Comment: Yeah you're right, turns out CT Zhu's answer doesn't work at all :/ think you have to treat each item (median, caps, boxes, etc) separately

Comment: @pceccon: I was wrong to assume CT Zhu's answer works; it doesn't. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just one more question if you have time... The boxes return 5 elements for x and 5 for y. Why does it means (I don't know how of them to choose, I was expecting at maximum 4 elements)? There is an reference about it?

Comment: A box has 4 edges, which when plotting have 5 nodes. (Start node is duplicated at the end).

Comment: How is `res` defined?

Comment: @Bastiaan : good spot - it starts as an empty `dict`; I could have used a dict comprehension but thought the loop would be more accessible to a wider audience. I've updated the snippet to include the initialisation.